# Div positioning with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some divs which position I define via jquery:

```
    var top=61;
    var left=255;
$("#number_"+ticketValues[0]).css("position","absolute");
$("#number_"+ticketValues[0]).css("top","60px");
$("#number_"+ticketValues[0]).css("left",left+"px");
```

This code successfully creates divs like this:

```
<div id="number_2344" style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 255px;">2344</div>
```

But when I change it to

```
$("#number_"+ticketValues[0]).css("top",top+"px");
```

for some reason it is like this:

```
<div id="number_2344" style="position: absolute; left: 255px;">2344</div>
```

How can I add top value dynamically?

Comment: Is there any other code between setting the value `top` and using it to apply style?

Comment: jsfiddle.net that shows the issue

Comment: In theory, this code should work, show us any other code that could be preventing it from working.

Comment: Works fine in this example http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/nhHfj/1/  There must be something else affecting it.  Incidentally, see the commented code for alternative method.

Comment: Please note that the jQuery CSS methods does not require you to add `px` to the numbers. It will do that for you if you just specify numbers!

Comment: Call `console.log(top);` to print the value of `top`. maybe it is `undefined`

Comment: Lol, console.log(top) returns some "Window" element.

Comment: `top` is a property of `window`, but `left` is not. Your code is running with `window` as the current `this`/scope and it is taking precedence. Answer updated below.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears correct unless something else is modifying `top`.

Note: You do not need the +"px" anywhere with jQuery as the `css` method adds it to numbers automatically.

You can also combine multiple CSS properties if you use the `css` method that takes an object.

### e.g. try this http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/nhHfj/2/

```
var top = 61;
var left = 255;
$("#number").css({position: "absolute", top: top, left: left});
```

To see if "something else" is modifying `top`, just rename it to another name in your code.

### Update:

Checking the [docs](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) for `window` I see `top` is a property, but `left` is not. That is taking precedence over your `var top` as your code is running in the scope of window (i.e. `this` is `window`).

### Solution:

Do not use `top` (or any other property of `window`) as a the name of a variable, when your code is running in the scope of `window` :)

If your code had been in a function, it would have worked fine (which is why all the JSFiddles work, as the code is wrapped in another scope).

### Proper solution:

This all implies your code is running outside a jQuery load event (which is a no no).

Change it to:

```
$(function(){
    var top = 61;
    var left = 255;
    $("#number").css({position: "absolute", top: top, left: left});
});
```

Which will run it inside another scope and avoid the naming problem. The load event handling also means the DOM is fully loaded before the code runs.

Note: `$(function(){...});` is just a shorthand for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`